# Graphql Apollo Federation

Tags: javascript, graphql, apollo, federation

I believe I understand how to extend types with the @key when I need to use different services between each other. Going to give an example in case I, a newbie to this, am incorrect in my understanding. For instance if I have a service for `Accounts` and one for `Users` and in the latter I have something like,

```
type Users @key(fields: "accountIds") {
  id: ID!
  accountIds: [ID]
}
```

I would extend this by adding a file in my `Accounts` service to extend `Users` like:

```
extend type Users @key(fields: "accountIds") {
    accountIds: [ID] @external
    accounts: [Accounts!]
}
```

I would also need to add a resolver to set what `accounts` should be. First thing, is the above correct? Do I understand what I am doing or did I miss something?

Next. How would I handle a type that, in an existing codebase that was NOT federated, looks like:
`union AccountResult = Accounts | SelectedAccounts`

If I need to use that `AccountResult` as a type in some other services how would I make it available? I don't see how I could do that given what I have above. Again, I'm new to this so I appreciate your patience.

Comment: The first part looks okay to me. I assume that you made it work before you try to add the SelectedAccount stuff, so you should know the answer to your first question pair ;-)
I'm not sure I get your second answer, though. AFAIU all services need to be at least federation-enabled (mainly adding `@key` directives) if you want extend the data they return..

Answer (score 2):

In **Users Federated Service**

```
type Users @key(fields: "id") {
  id: ID!
  accountIds: [String]
}
```

In **Accounts Federated Service** extend the Users Type

```
extend type Users @key(fields: "id") {
    id: ID! @external
    accounts: [Accounts]
}
```

**Accounts Type** in Accounts Federated Service might look something like this;

```
type Accounts @key(fields: "id") {
      id: ID!
      accountHolderId: String!
      accountType: String!
      amount: Float!
    }
```

After that inside the **Resolver** of **Accounts Federated Service**, write something like this to resolve the **accounts field** in the extended Users Type

```
const resolver = {
  Users: {
    async accounts(users) {

     // get account ids array of users using users.accountId
     // you can make a DB call and get Accounts Service Data and filter ids 
     // of those retrieved data with users.accountId data
     // finally return filtered data

    }
  }
}
```

"async accounts" method have a signature like this in the resolver;
***async accounts(parent data, values passed, context, info) {  }***
I have used **users** parameter as **parent data** other parameters are optional
Apart from that, you can use the **Resolve Reference** ( __resolveReference(ref) ) Method to attach data from one service to another service.